# reactjs not updating socketio state properly in useState

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, use-state

This seems to be very obvious, but couldnt figure why this is not working.

```
const [socketio, setSocketio] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
            console.log("setting socket");  //this print comes
            const socketRes = io("http://localhost:8700/");
            console.log(socketRes); //this prints socket details fine
            setSocketio(socketRes);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("socket id " + socketio.id); //this prints always undefined

    }, [socketio]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found to get id in your frontend is to add a listener.

```
socketRes.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socketRes.id);
});
```